# Matrix norm equal to sum of norms of column vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        {a_1}_1 & {a_1}_2 & \cdots & {a_1}_n\\
        {a_2}_1 & {a_2}_2 & \cdots & {a_2}_n \\
        \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
        {a_m}_1 & {a_m}_2 & \cdots & {a_m}_n \\
        \end{bmatrix} = 
     \begin{bmatrix}
        \vec a_1 & \vec a_2 & \cdots & \vec a_n\end{bmatrix}$$

The Frobenius norm of matrix $A$ is

$$||A||_F = \sqrt{\mathrm{tr} (A^\top A)} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n |{a_i}_j|^2} \tag{1}$$

If I take $||A||_F^2$, can I write it as

$$||A||_F^2=\sum_{j=1}^n ||\vec a_j||^2 \tag{2}$$

Is equation $(2)$ mathematically right?

Comment: It's correct, although $a_i$ should be $\vec a_i$.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the result if you just plug in the definition of $\|a_i\|$?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I just edited the eq.(2), $a_i$ is a vector; $\vec a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes.

To see it, just look at what happens if you expand the definition of the vector norm in your equation (2) and take its square.

Comment: If you are going to answer a question, answer it; don't ask another question.

Comment: Just putting OP on the rails to see why his answer is valid.

Comment: I tried it with $2 \times 2$ matrix, it seems it is true but I just wanted to be sure and asked for your opinions for confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure my notations are clear, let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
        {a_1}_1 & {a_1}_2 & \cdots & {a_1}_n\\
        {a_2}_1 & {a_2}_2 & \cdots & {a_2}_n \\
        \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
        {a_m}_1 & {a_m}_2 & \cdots & {a_m}_n \\
        \end{bmatrix} = 
     \begin{bmatrix}
        |  & |  &  & | \\
        a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\
        |  & |  &  & | \\
     \end{bmatrix}$$
where $a_j \in \mathbb{R}^m$ for all $j = 1, \ldots, n$.

As was answered in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2429027/571583), you can check that you equation (2) is valid by computing:
$$||A||_F^2 \overset{eq. (1)}{=} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n ||a_j||_2^2$$

Here is another, an more visual, answer to this question. One common definition of the Frobenius norm is the following (form real matrices): $||A||_F := \sqrt{\mathrm{tr} (A^\top A)}$. So, to compute the squared Frobenius norm of $A$, one can sum the diagonal terms of $A^\top A$, ie, 
$$||A||_F^2 = \mathrm{tr} (A^\top A) = \sum_{j=1}^n (A^\top A)_{jj}$$

Let us then visualize what we have the diagonal of this matrix product:

\begin{align*}
 ~   & \,  
    \begin{bmatrix}
        |  & |  &  & | \\
        a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \\
        |  & |  &  & | \\
    \end{bmatrix}                   \\
%
    A^\top A =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        - & a_1^\top & - \\
          & \vdots   &   \\
        - & a_n^\top & - \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    &
    \begin{bmatrix} 
||a_1||_2^2   & * & * \\
*                          & \ddots & * \\
*  & * & ||a_n||_2^2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

So, when you compute the trace, you recover the sum of the squared norms.